# How can I do the following in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need to rewrite

1. site.com/blog.php?blogger=somebody to somebody.site.com
2. site.com/blog.php?blogger=somebody&content=sth&page=nxt to
   somebody.site.com/sth/nxt

using .htaccess

Comment: Just rewriting will not work. You need some additional steps to handle CNAMES for sub-domains too that are generated.

Comment: Can you please provide me the additional steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^blogger=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://%1.site.com [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^blogger=(.*)&content=(.*)&page=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://%1.site.com/%2/%3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It is showing 404 error when i try to view somebody.mysite.com

Comment: Does `somebody.mysite.com` actually have an `index` page?

Comment: No no , it doesnt ! I have a file blog.php?blogger=somebody&content=sth&page=next and i used your .htaccess codes and when i visited somebody.site.com it showed 404 error !! I have no any files or directories on the site except blog.php

Comment: What about if you disable the code i provided? Still 404 happens?

Comment: Yeah ! Site.com is working now also but when i visit somebody.site.com it gives a 404 error ! Yeah i tried it by removing your codes too but its again giving 404 error on visiting somebody.site.com

Comment: Then `somebody.site.com` may be broken.

Comment: I dont think so , as when i visit site.com/blog.php?blogger=somebody then its displaying the profile of somebody but when i visit somebody.site.com it gives 404 error ! I am using freewha.com server

Comment: It's not related to the redirection rules. Make sure your target URLs actually exist.